# SQL adjacency list query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2017

Trying to model dependencies on a service that is accessed by users. I have created a parent/child adjacency list style table that sets out that 'the service' relies on Component 1, which relies on Component 2, etc, etc. and the type of dependency e.g. full or partial

This image shows the layout - Dependencies image

[image]

Comp 1 & 9 are coloured differently because if they fail then overall service fails. If any of Comp 2-9 fail then the service continues but just has reduced resiliency.

Here is what I have used to create the table

```
CREATE TABLE scratch
( 
    KeyID        int    PRIMARY KEY        NOT NULL, 
    CompDesc       varchar(30), 
    CompID        int    NOT NULL, 
    ReliesOn       int    NOT NULL, 
    RelianceType       varchar(30), 
)

INSERT scratch SELECT 0, 'Service', 0, 1, 'Full'
INSERT scratch SELECT 1, 'Component 1', 1, 2, 'Partial'
INSERT scratch SELECT 2, 'Component 1', 1, 3, 'Partial'
INSERT scratch SELECT 3, 'Component 1', 1, 4, 'Partial'
INSERT scratch SELECT 4, 'Component 4', 4, 5, 'Full'
INSERT scratch SELECT 5, 'Component 5', 5, 6, 'Full'
INSERT scratch SELECT 6, 'Component 6', 6, 7, 'Partial'
INSERT scratch SELECT 7, 'Component 6', 6, 8, 'Partial'
INSERT scratch SELECT 8, 'Component 2', 2, 9, 'Full'
INSERT scratch SELECT 9, 'Component 3', 3, 9, 'Full'
INSERT scratch SELECT 10, 'Component 7', 7, 9, 'Full'
INSERT scratch SELECT 11, 'Component 8', 8, 9, 'Full'
```

I can then run a very crude query to show the 4 different options the users can access the service -

```
SELECT t1.ReliesOn AS lev1, t2.ReliesOn as lev2, t3.ReliesOn as lev3, t4.ReliesOn as lev4, t5.ReliesOn as lev5, t6.ReliesOn as lev6
FROM Scratch AS t1
LEFT JOIN Scratch AS t2 ON t2.CompID = t1.ReliesOn
LEFT JOIN Scratch AS t3 ON t3.CompID = t2.ReliesOn
LEFT JOIN Scratch AS t4 ON t4.CompID = t3.ReliesOn
LEFT JOIN Scratch AS t5 ON t5.CompID = t4.ReliesOn
LEFT JOIN Scratch AS t6 ON t6.CompID = t5.ReliesOn
WHERE t1.ReliesOn = 1;
```

(Apologies, there is probably a better way of stringing that query together)

with this result -

```
lev1    lev2    lev3    lev4    lev5    lev6
1       2       9       NULL    NULL    NULL
1       3       9       NULL    NULL    NULL
1       4       5       6       7       9
1       4       5       6       8       9
```

What I am trying to do is create a query that I can set out the comp(s) that have failed and determine if the service is still available e.g.

```
Failed      Result
1           No Service
2,3         Reduced Resiliency
3,8         Reduced Resiliency
2,3,7,8     No Service
```

This is just a very simple example, I have many more that I need to add to this, and in the majority of cases a number of services will rely on the same components.

So, how do you go from the failed comp and go up/across/down the dependencies to figure out if a path still exists?

Hopefully, this makes sense

Thanks

Comment: how can someone knows that 'Component 9' is the 'entry point' and not, for example, 'component 2'? Also, why 'Component 9' is not in your sample data?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. This will be used for modelling service availability in the event of comp failure. I don't think there is a need to someone to know the entry point.

I didn't include Comp 9 in the sample data as it doesn't have any dependencies. I suppose I could add

INSERT scratch SELECT 12, 'Component 9', 9, NULL, NULL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to write a query that does this using [Recursive CTEs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx).

First, I took the liberty of adding two more records to the `scratch` table:

```
INSERT scratch SELECT 12, 'Component 9', 9, 10, 'Full'
INSERT scratch SELECT 13, 'Users', 10, 10, 'Full'
```

This means that:

- 9 relies on 10 (User) as shown in the diagram
- 10 relies on itself (which means in this case that 10 is the terminal component - the one that has to be up for the Service to be avilable).

In the query, the components that are not available should have their ids enumerated in the `FailedComponents` CTE:

```
with FailedComponents (id) as (
  select id from (values
    (1), (7), (8)
    ) x(id)
), OnlineComponents (compId, reliesOn) as (
  select compId, reliesOn
  from scratch
  where compId = 0 -- <== entry point here
  union all
  select s.compId, s.reliesOn
  from scratch s
  join OnlineComponents c
    on s.compId = c.reliesOn
  where s.compId not in (select id from FailedComponents)
)
select case
  when exists (select * from OnlineComponents where compId = reliesOn)
    then 'Service is available'
    else 'No Service'
  end as [Status]
;
```

Here's the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/16dad/11) where you can try out different values to see how the query handles them.

Note that the query does not use the `Full`/`Partial` reliance type that is specified in the `scratch` table. The reliance types are inferred from the context. Basically if there's a way to cross the graph from 0 to 10 walking only on available components, the service as a whole is available.

Also, a little warning: there's a limit to how deep the recursive CTE will go. This is called `MAXRECURSION` and has a default of 100. You need to change it to a higher value if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the result query is not an easy one. I post an approach to you, you can play with it on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a8b56/6)

**MS SQL Server 2014 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE scratch
( 
    KeyID        int    PRIMARY KEY        NOT NULL, 
    CompDesc       varchar(30), 
    CompID        int    NOT NULL, 
    ReliesOn       int     NULL, --null to allow node 9
    RelianceType       varchar(30), 
)

INSERT scratch SELECT 0, 'Service', 0, 1, 'Full'
INSERT scratch SELECT 1, 'Component 1', 1, 2, 'Partial'
INSERT scratch SELECT 2, 'Component 1', 1, 3, 'Partial'
INSERT scratch SELECT 3, 'Component 1', 1, 4, 'Partial'
INSERT scratch SELECT 4, 'Component 4', 4, 5, 'Full'
INSERT scratch SELECT 5, 'Component 5', 5, 6, 'Full'
INSERT scratch SELECT 6, 'Component 6', 6, 7, 'Partial'
INSERT scratch SELECT 7, 'Component 6', 6, 8, 'Partial'
INSERT scratch SELECT 8, 'Component 2', 2, 9, 'Full'
INSERT scratch SELECT 9, 'Component 3', 3, 9, 'Full'
INSERT scratch SELECT 10, 'Component 7', 7, 9, 'Full'
INSERT scratch SELECT 11, 'Component 8', 8, 9, 'Full'
INSERT scratch SELECT 12, 'Component 9', 9, Null, 'Full' --node 9 added
```

Here the **query** to figure up alive paths:

```
with 
from_to as ( select 9 as [from], 1 as [to] ),
failed_nodes as ( select 3 as f union select 4 ), --list of failed nodes
cte as (
   select *
          ,CAST(CompID AS VARCHAR(255)) AS Path
   from scratch
   where CompId = (select [from] from from_to ) -easy: ReliesOn is null
   union all
   select s.*
          ,CAST(Path + '.' + CAST(s.CompID AS VARCHAR(255)) AS VARCHAR(255))
   from scratch s
   inner join cte on s.ReliesOn = cte.CompID
   where s.compid not in ( select * from failed_nodes)
)
select * from cte
```

Just check for `keyID = 0` in **[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a8b56/6/0)** results to know if service is still available and the alive paths (is a simple `where`):

```
| KeyID |    CompDesc | CompID | ReliesOn | RelianceType |    Path |
|-------|-------------|--------|----------|--------------|---------|
|    12 | Component 9 |      9 |   (null) |         Full |       9 |
|     8 | Component 2 |      2 |        9 |         Full |     9.2 |
|    10 | Component 7 |      7 |        9 |         Full |     9.7 |
|    11 | Component 8 |      8 |        9 |         Full |     9.8 |
|     7 | Component 6 |      6 |        8 |      Partial |   9.8.6 |
|     5 | Component 5 |      5 |        6 |         Full | 9.8.6.5 |
|     6 | Component 6 |      6 |        7 |      Partial |   9.7.6 |
|     5 | Component 5 |      5 |        6 |         Full | 9.7.6.5 |
|     1 | Component 1 |      1 |        2 |      Partial |   9.2.1 |
|     0 |     Service |      0 |        1 |         Full | 9.2.1.0 < still alive
```

Also, adapt this solution to your scenario to deal with `RelianceType` nodes.